# Servlet Initialization parameters using annotation

Tags: servlets, annotations

I am trying to learn Servlet annotations and came across this snippet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/MyPattern", initParams={@WebInitParam(name="ccc", value="333")})
```

This makes sense to me. However, I don't understand why it is not like this

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/MyPattern", initParams={(name="ccc", value="333"), (name="abc", value="1")})
```

So, the question is why we need to put `@WebInitParam` annotation when we already declared the attribute as `initParams`. It seems redundant to me, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative you suggest would not even compile.

When you look at the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1), it states this:

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.

So in order to group `name` and `value` together, which represent the initialization parameter the only option is to use annotation (`@WebInitParam` in this case) with corresponding values set as its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As with most questions about language design choices we can only speculate here. I think some reasons for this are:

1. Keeping the language simple.
   It is kind of redundant, but the syntax for annotations can be reused and does not require new language constructs. This makes it easier to parse and to read. Sure, It's longer, but it's also more explicit to write the annotation's name.
2. Don't restrict possible future language enhancements.
   The proposed syntax would not work if annotations would support inheritance. I don't know if that's even a planned feature but it would not be possible to implement straightforward it if the type can be omitted.

In many cases an array of annotations seems like a workaround anyway. It can be avoided in Java 8, where you can add multiple annotations of the same type:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/MyPattern")
@WebInitParam(name="ccc", value="333")
@WebInitParam(name="abc", value="1")
```

(I don't know if the servlet api actually supports this yet though)